# Recursive values in 4th order RK method for projectile (quadratic drag) in C

Tags: c

I am trying to code projectile motion of a shell using 4th order RK method. I am facing a problem in the following code.

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i=i+1)
{
    ax[i]= (-kk[i]*v[i]*vx[i])/m;
    ay[i]= ((-kk[i]*v[i]*vy[i])-(m*g))/m;
    k1= ax[i];
    m1= ay[i];
    k2= (-kk[i]*v[i]*(vx[i]+(k1*delt/2)))/m;
    m2=  (-kk[i]*v[i]*(vy[i]+(m1*delt/2)))/m;
    k3= (-kk[i]*v[i]*(vx[i]+(k2*delt/2)))/m;
    m3=  (-kk[i]*v[i]*(vy[i]+(m2*delt/2)))/m;
    k4= (-kk[i]*v[i]*(vx[i]+(k3*delt)))/m;
    m4=  (-kk[i]*v[i]*(vy[i]+(m3*delt)))/m;
    vx[i+1]= vx[i]+((1/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*delt);
    vy[i+1]= vy[i]+((1/6)*(m1+2*m2+2*m3+m4)*delt);
    x[i+1]= vx[i+1]*delt;
    y[i+1]= vy[i+1]*delt;
    xx[i+1]= x[i+1] + xx[i];
    yy[i+1]= y[i+1] + yy[i];
    t[i+1]= t[i]+delt;
    v[i+1]= sqrt((vx[i+1]*vx[i+1])+(vy[i+1]*vy[i+1]));
    if ((yy[i+1]<0)&&(i!=1))
        //if (i==100)
    {
        nn=i;
        i=n;
    }
    printf ("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t\n", t[i], vx[i], vy[i], v[i], xx[i], yy[i]);
```

In the above code `ax`, `ay`, `vx` and `vy` are accelerations and velocity in x and y directions, `delt` represents the time step. `xx` and `yy` are the position of the corresponding time steps. 
After using fourth order RK method I try to find the velocities in the next time step to obtain the corresponding values in the loop until the projectile hits the ground. But I am only getting the same values as of `vx[1]` and `vy[1]` for every corresponding iteration and repeats.I am a beginner in C programming and still at an initial stage of using loops.

Comment: I suggest that you use the Runge kutta from Boost, althogh you need to use C++.

Comment: Read about a [mcve]. That link provides excellent information how to reduce a problem to something that is small enough to understand or to ask a specific question. That said, if you ever post code asking people to read it, make sure it is well readable. In particular, make sure you have consistent formatting.

Comment: `1/6` Integer division. This will always be `0`.

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=n; i=i+1)` You copied this fragment from the *Numerical Recipes in C* book? And,even if so: are you sure that `vx[i+1]` does not address the array(s) out of bounds?

Comment: Please learn about `//` and `/* */` and use them.  Who ever has to look at this code later on will appreciate it.

Comment: @schorsch312 it's not necessary to use C++, once you know the mathematical procedure behind the formulas, any language can be used. Anyways, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @wildplasser How can one say that the loop is copied? I guess that's the ubiquitous loop text one uses and nobody owns it's copyrights. To address your second question, yes I am sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
vx[i+1]= vx[i]+((1/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*delt);
vy[i+1]= vy[i]+((1/6)*(m1+2*m2+2*m3+m4)*delt);
```

`1/6` - both numbers are integers so this will result in `0` making your statements:

```
vx[i+1]= vx[i];
vy[i+1]= vy[i];
```

Make them floating point. And since you calculate often, make it a constant.

```
const double one_sixth = 1.0 / 6.0;
```

Then

```
vx[i+1]= vx[i]+(one_sixth * (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*delt);
vy[i+1]= vy[i]+(one_sixth * (m1+2*m2+2*m3+m4)*delt);
```